# Counting Number 1's of Band_Name

Tags: sql, count

Hey I am trying to use a count to show the total amount of number ones a band has had, so far i have:

```
SELECT cds.cd_id,cds.position,bands.band_name
FROM cds
INNER JOIN releases
INNER join bands
ON cds.cd_id =releases.cd_id and releases.band_id = bands.band_id
Where band_name IS NOT NULL AND position = 1;

SELECT bands.band_name, COUNT(band_name) AS Total FROM bands
WHERE band_name ='Prodigy';
```

This will join the tables together with the position cd_id and band_name then use a count to count how many Number ones the band 'Prodigy' has had

```
cd020   1   Prodigy
cd021   1   Prodigy
cd024   1   Kylie Minogue
cd028   1   Kylie Minogue
cd031   1   Kylie Minogue
cd049   1   Kylie Minogue
cd065   1   Robbie Williams
cd068   1   Robbie Williams
cd070   1   Robbie Williams
```

as you can see Prodigy should of had 2 number 1 positions and my count only shows it having and i assume that it would be the easiest way to count the number of times the band_name appears rather than the number of positions for each band. any help or advice that you could give would be very helpful

Comment: What table contains the position field?

Comment: The position field is in the cds table, the cd_id is in both cds and bands table, band_name is in bands table

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate queries need a `GROUP BY` statement. Like so:

```
SELECT bands.band_name, COUNT(band_name) AS Total FROM bands
WHERE band_name ='Prodigy'
GROUP BY bands.band_name;
```

To get your result, use something like this:

```
SELECT
    bands.band_name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    cds
        INNER JOIN
    releases ON (cds.cd_id =releases.cd_id)
        INNER JOIN
    bands ON (releases.band_id = bands.band_id)
WHERE
    bands.band_name IS NOT NULL
    AND cds.position = 1
GROUP BY bands.band_name;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the derived table?

Comment: @DanBracuk, That's a damn good question. Looking at it again, it's not really at all necessary. Edit to come.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT cds.position, bands.band_name, COUNT(cds.cd_id) as COUNT
FROM cds
    INNER JOIN releases
    INNER join bands
        ON cds.cd_id =releases.cd_id and releases.band_id = bands.band_id
WHERE band_name IS NOT NULL AND position = 1
GROUP BY bands.band_name, cds.position;
```